# Casting '0' to double precision, then multiple by -1 will result in negative zero

Tags: postgresql, double, precision, negative-zero

I'm trying to negate a double precision value inside jsonb data. I had to cast it to double since PG will return it as text.
I found that zero value are printed as -0

Is that fine? how to fix it without "CASE WHEN"

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `-0`?

Comment: @Bergi What if a web app converts this value to string? isn't it problematic?

Comment: Depends on whether you care that the user does not see the minus sign? But no, JavaScript in a web app would handle negative zero just fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you add 0.0 to the result, it will normalize it to regular 0.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bergi asked: What is the problem? The properties of 0 and -0 are exactly the same. Run:

```
select '0 vs. -0. they are ' ||
       case when ( 0 = -0) 
            then 'Equal'
            else 'Not Equal'
       end;
```

Also see demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=71dbab2a8d5bc8c3d9e0f5819c3a1eed). In all cases the results are the same. Multiplication produces -0 instead of 0, but since they are the same they can be freely substituted.

Comment: Nice comparison table. Is this specified somewhere in the postgres documentation? I also tried out floating point operations that one would normally expect to distinguish them (`1/x`, `ln`, `log`, `cot`, `atan2`, `sign`), but they all have the same results with positive and negative zero. The only way of distinguishing them seems to be the `::text` cast.

Comment: AFAIK nothing in the documentation, it's just the math. I had also looked at the logical functions (bitwise AND, OR, etc) but that requires casting to integer which turns -0 into 0 ( further conversion with ::text doesn't distinguishing them. Select (-0)::int4::text;)